# Error 401 : When ESP32 use HttpRequest to update data on Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, http, google-cloud-firestore, httprequest, esp32

Now I can fetch data from Cloud Firestore to show in Arduino IDE but when I want to update data on Cloud Firestore I cannot. It's show Error 401.
apiKey : correct
projectID : correct
WiFi connection : connected
API Restrict : None
I stuck in this problem for 4 hours

```
void updatePointsInFirestore(const String& documentID, int newPoints) {
  // Construct the Firestore URL for the specific document
  String firestoreURL = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + String(projectId) +
                        "/databases/(default)/documents/users/" + documentID;

  // Prepare the JSON payload with the new Points value
  String payload = "{\"fields\":{\"Points\":{\"integerValue\":" + String(newPoints) + "}}}";

  // Make the HTTP PATCH request to update the Points field
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(firestoreURL);

  // Add the Authorization header with the API Key
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + String(apiKey));
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  int httpCode = http.sendRequest("PATCH", payload);

  if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    Serial.println("Points updated successfully in Firestore.");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Error updating Points in Firestore. HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpCode);
  }

  http.end(); // Close the connection
}
```

I try to create a new project to get new ProjectID and apiKey but it's still Erorr.
I think the problem is on ESP32